# knife bootstrap --sudo not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to bootstrap an amazon aws instance with the command:

```
knife bootstrap 50.60.71.109 -N {node_name} -d {distro} -E {environment} -x ubuntu -i ~/.ssh/my-key.pem --sudo
```

but the output I get suggests that it's not using sudo correctly:

```
52.60.71.109 usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
52.60.71.109 usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
52.60.71.109 usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
52.60.71.109             [command]
52.60.71.109 usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
52.60.71.109             prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
52.60.71.109 usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
52.60.71.109             prompt] [-u user] file ...
52.60.71.109 E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
...
```

The server is an ec2 ubuntu 14.04 instance.

My version of knife is `11.16.4`

Comment: do you have password less  sudo access for ubuntu user??

Comment: read knife bootstrap help: "-d, --distro DISTRO              Bootstrap a distro using a template. **[DEPRECATED]** Use -t / --bootstrap-template option instead.
"

Comment: Yes, the server is set up for passwordless sudo.